# Why can't I access two different web pages using same cookie in this code [PHP-CURL]?

Tags: php, php-curl

I am trying to write a script to login to a particular site and obtain multiple web pages in the site to php variables. Here I am using the same cookie in both curl requests.

In the attached code, first curl request returns the home page, but the second requests return the login page instead of the requested page(it seems that it is counted as a new request). I am using the same cookie file in both occasions.

```
<?php
$username='xxxxx';
$password='xxxxxxx';
$cookie="C:/Games/cookie21.txt";

$url = 'http://xxxx/xxx/login.php';
$postdata = "?&uname=$username&upwd=$password";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);

$url1 = 'http:///xxxx/xxx/forms/personal_info.php';
$ch1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url1);
$result1 = curl_exec ($ch1);
echo $result1;
curl_close($ch1);
?>
```

Can someone explain the reason for this odd behavior and the modification needed in this code to obtain multiple web pages in a site to php variables using php-curl?

Comment: `If the cookie jar file can't be created or written to (when the curl_easy_cleanup is called), libcurl will not and cannot report an error for this` are you sure the file path is writable by the PHP user.

Comment: There is a cookie file created in the above location (C:/Games/cookie21.txt). How can I check whether the cookie file can be written again? I am running this code in xampp in windows

Comment: in code you can use `is_writable()`   http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php  That said the presence of the file, (if it didn't exist to begin with) should be enough to tell you.